Passing a Model through a Remote Function
I am having trouble passing a model through a remote event
the model (tower) is stored originally in replicated storage before being cloned and moved a folder in the workspace
(local script)
tower = game.ReplicatedStorage.Towers.Boxer:Clone()
        
tower.Parent = workspace.Map.TowersToPlace

Then I pass it through the remote event.
print(tower)    replicatedStorage.SpawnTowerEvent:FireServer(tower, mouse.Hit.Position)
end)

The print line is printing the tower correctly but the server script is erroring saying the tower variable is nil
(server script)
game.ReplicatedStorage.SpawnTowerEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr, towerToPlace, pos)
    print(towerToPlace)
end)

-- returns nil
Anyone know why the variable is not being passed despite being defined correctly in the local script.

Why are you trying to pass the model itself through the remote event? I would think it would make more sense to have logic in the remote event handler that can look up where the cloned part is stored in the local workspace. Can you explain more of your use  case? I would also like a pastebin or something of your full script for context
